# trash the suit - pretend to be innocent?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Though Georgia officials were quick to **trash the suit** — “the Biden Administration continues to do the bidding of Stacey Abrams and spreads more lies about Georgia’s election law,” Secretary of State Brad Raffensperger (R) said — the 46-page complaint quoted Georgia Republicans several times to drive the point home.

Source: [Talking Points Memo](https://talkingpointsmemo.com/)

I understand "trash the suit" as "pretend to be innocent (show a gesture of "I did nothing at all")." Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

"Trash" here means "disparage", to say that the suit has no merit, is pointless, or is political propaganda without legal  validity.  In this case Raffensperger  described the allegations in the suit as "lies" which is certainly a disparaging comment.

"Trash" is used informally as a verb. [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/trash_2) gives sense 2 as "to criticize someone or something in a very strong way" which is the sense used here.

While Raffensperger and the other Georgia officials no doubt claim not to have done anything wrong, "trash" here has nothing to do with "pretending innocence".

Georgia has passed a new law regulating elections. The Federal DoJ has sued, claiming that this law violates the constitution and denies voters their rights.  Raffensperger, on behalf of the state of Georgia, says that these claims are "lies" and that the suit is designed to support the political aims of  Stacey Abrams, a former Democratic candidate for Governor of Georgia and a major force in the 2020 Senate elections in Georgia.

Answer (score 5):

No. A *suit* is a legal process in court. They are claming that the case is rubbish ("trash").

Comment: In the context of the OP, does it say that Secretary of State Brad Raffensperger (R) insisted attacking the Biden Administration?

Comment: @NewPlanet The quote says that Raffensperger  claimed that the Biden Administration was "spreading lies" and acting improperly. It didn't use the word 'insisted" or any word of similar meaning.

Comment: "Trash" here is being used as a verb, see the link in my answer. I think this is a largely US usage.

Comment: No, _trash_ as a verb is just as common elsewhere: I didn't think it necessary to explain it.